# Erreur: HTTPConnectionPool(host='dnode2', port=9864): Max retries exceeded with url: /webhdfs

Tags: python, django, hadoop, hdfs, webhdfs

I'm trying to read a file on my hdfs server in my python app deployed with docker, during dev, I don't have any problem, but in prod there are this error :

> Erreur:  HTTPConnectionPool(host='dnode2', port=9864): Max retries
> exceeded with url:
> /webhdfs/v1/?op=OPEN&namenoderpcaddress=namenode:9000&offset=0
> (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection
> object at 0x7f1af13d45d0>: Failed to establish a new connection:
> [Errno -2] Name or service not known'))

Note that I use an address IP not that "dnode2" name and neither use that port!!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but It was just that I needed to add a static mapping in my /etc/hosts and it's work!!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While it may work, you shouldn't be editing your hosts file to fix hadoop or Docker networking problems.